# Delete only one record in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

what is the proper way to delete only one record from mysql data base.
this query used for select only one record.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Mexico' ORDER BY Country  ASC LIMIT 1;
```

the above query run correctly .but when replace select to delete that not worked.

```
DELETE FROM Customers WHERE Country='Mexico' ORDER BY Country  ASC LIMIT 1;
```

how I can fix it?

Comment: remove `ORDER BY Country  ASC` from delete clause

Comment: because of my reason i can not remove it

Comment: Deleting a single record without using a primary key or a unique key is a recipe for diaster

Comment: I did not understand delete with limit 1 deletes exactly one record now what is your additional conditions please specify into the question.

Comment: @Strawberry How can you guarantee that that specific record is going to be deleted? If I write a delete statement to delete the most recent record (the one I want) and someone adds a new record, I delete the wrong record

Comment: @Strawberry Hah :D I was wondering who would advocate deleting single records with generic statements!

Comment: It is supposed to work the query seems correct if you see the manual `DELETE FROM somelog WHERE user = 'jcole'
ORDER BY timestamp_column LIMIT 1;`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html

Comment: could not prepare statement (1 near "LIMIT":syntax error) that is the error

Comment: So you're using a prepared statement somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an id column you can use a subselect. I have removed the order by since this will be the same like `order by 'Mexico' asc` which is pretty useless.

```
    DELETE FROM Customers
WHERE (CustomerID IN ( SELECT CustomerID
                  FROM Customers where country = 'Mexico'
                  ORDER BY CustomerID ASC LIMIT 1 )) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think below query will help you. You will need to have some key ID to differentiate.

```
DELETE FROM Customers 
WHERE SOME_KEY_ID IN 
(
  SELECT SOME_RANDOM_ID FROM
  (
            SELECT B.SOME_KEY_ID SOME_RANDOM_ID  FROM Customers as B 
            where Country = 'Mexico'
            LIMIT 1
   )     as c 
 )  ;
```

Note: The inner select SOME_RANDOM_ID is required, else sqlfiddle throws errors `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery':` .

[Reference FIDDLE Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e0a8b/1)

Comment: @adib16: The query accepted as answer, does not even compile. Refer fiddle here. <http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e0a8b/1>. Are you sure you accepted "overflowed's" answer after trying?